# How to extract the string from between the Nth and N+1th occurence of a character in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a column that contains a list of one or more database names. Unfortunately, the turnaround time to get this report altered is long. So I need to manipulate the data.

The column contains all the databases specific to a record in a single cell, separated by commas. I need to pull this list apart and place each database in a separate cell. Important note: I am **not** allowed to use VBA macros/code in this solution.

The first one is easy: Find the first comma, return everything to left of that. It's the next ones that I'm struggling with.

I've created a column that counts how many commas there are in the cell, so I can determine if multiple databases is listed.

How can I tackle the next ones?

Comment: Use text to columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a worksheet function answer, but it doesn't use VBA either.

Have you tried using the "Text to columns" feature?  In Excel 2010, it's one of the buttons on the Data ribbon.

1. Select your column.
2. Click the "Text to columns" button.
3. On the first page of the wizard, choose "Delimited", then Next.
4. On the second page, tick "Comma" to choose it as the delimiter.  You may want to tick/untick some of the others depending on the format of your data.
5. You can probably click Finish at this point to split your data into columns, but you might want to go to the next page to change the column formats.

Answer (score 1):

With sample data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If we start with material in columns **A** and **B** like this:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   K = 1

   For i = 2 To N
      v = Cells(i, "A").Value
      ary = Split(Cells(i, "B").Value, ",")
      For Each a In ary
         Cells(K, "C").Value = v
         Cells(K, "D").Value = a
         K = K + 1
      Next a
   Next i
End Sub
```

we will end up with this:

[image]

Comment: I've just been handed a new requirement to match up the person associated with list of databases. So this solution suddenly becomes interesting. Could you please unpack the function? For example my list of databases is more like "Corporate Database 1, HR Database 3, Finance Database 67". I need the spaces to remain, so I can't just trim the results. Also, the database list is in column D. I'm ending up with a huge amount of extra spaces in the columns I drag into.

Comment: I do not understand the new requirement.

Comment: The report has a column for Name and a column with the list of databases. One name, many databases. Now, they want me to break it out so there is a row with name and single database. For each name and database association.

Comment: @DeNaeL  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: If you need a non-VBA way of doing this, the [Paste and Transpose](http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/transposing-data-in-excel-worksheets) feature may be helpful. Once you've split a database name into cells on a single row, you can use it to transpose them into columns, then copy'n'paste the names alongside.  I realise this could be a bit labour-intensive if you've got lots of rows to process though...